# Installing a legacy driver from the admin command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, command-prompt, drivers

```
regsvr32 C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_umpass.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_3e36a1bb590690c5\umpass.inf

regsvr32 C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\umpass.inf_amd64_neutral_e3be362bfab667d2\umpass.inf
```

Didn't seem to work.  Says it is not compatible (I am using a 64bit system).  I am trying to install a legacy driver (device manager) system - microsoft - ecpnode.  Is this the wrong command I am using or the wrong syntax? Thank you kindly.

Comment: I don't think `regsvr32` knows what to do with `.inf` files.  You can install drivers with `devcon` which I believe is available from the MS web site.  There may be other options that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I used Devon - works great!

Comment: devcon driver.inf hardwareid      -  I installed the driver then went into it's properties under device manager.  Then I looked up the hardware id and the original inf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy devcon64.exe c:\windows\system32

devcon64.exe install eaphost.inf eh\0

There is a 64bit devcon64 and a 32 bit devcon.  The eaphost.inf was the file's base driver and then looking up the hardware id in the device manager I found the eh\0